# Phonegap, Livecode, etc - pros and cons for a newbie? Should I still to learning Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, livecode

There seem to be quite a lot of "Build your iPhone app quickly" 3rd party solutions to Objective-C but am not sure if there is an advantage to any of them.  I am learning Objective-C through tutorials and creating example apps.  I feel I am learning slowly but nonetheless, I am learning it.  Are these 3rd party solutions good or bad?

Comment: This isn't a programming question. It is not clear what kind of problem you are trying to solve. You could have asked something like "I try to make an app in Objective-C and I have this code [insert code here]. What would this code look like in Phonegap?". Your question is likely to cause a very long debate and these debates don't belong on Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 5):

LiveCode is a good solution if you are interested in deploying the same app with perhaps some minor user interface tweaks on iOS, android, Windows, OS X, x86 Linux... soon Windows 8 & arm Linux too. There's also a server side scripting option so it's possible to implement a library that can be used across many platforms. The platform is also now open source with the first code drop due this month.

Answer (score 2):

I'd stay away from the build-a-bad-app-quickly tools, but I'm a little biased.

My only first-hand experience is with Titanium Appcelerator, but in that brief time I had to write a script to patch the auto-generated project source to work around a crash (and it either needed to be a script or a modification to the SDK, since the auto-generated code was overwritten every build). The UI API was far from easy to use, I found problems incredibly hard to debug since your code is converted to a compressed JavaScript blob running in an interpreter, and the incredible hoops it jumped through to pass things between the JS thread and the main thread pretty much ruled out extending it with any missing features. I'm *very* biased here, since that was a project recovery (ironically, the original developer ended up writing the Android version natively, and possibly spent more time trying to make a "cross-platform" version than it would've taken to do a native iOS version).

I've heard good things about PhoneGap *if all you need is a webview* with occasional things done in native code (the API for passing things between JS and native code is reported to be good), but that's a big "if" — it might be okay if you don't care about a "native" UI, or perhaps as a starting point from which you add native features.

Googling for PhoneGap gave an ad for trigger.io; I tested the apps I could on the [examples page](https://trigger.io/examples/):

- PlayerPro's login screen scrolls (a dead giveaway), the contentSize is 20 pixels too high, and does not use native Facebook login. The "Sign up with facebook" button image is stretched and does not change visibly when tapped.
- Fanium's login screen buttons do not change visibly when tapped. The "buttons" in the nav bar disappear and reappear when you press the login button.
- Hojoki's buttons aren't quite right. The login page scrolls vertically, but only in one direction (and it doesn't need to!). It does not use native Facebook login.
- Fetchnotes' intro screen has left/right buttons (with misaligned arrows) to scroll; you can't just scroll normally. The scrolling animation is not native. The back button on the login/signup screens is clearly not native and too close to the left side of the screen (all the non-native buttons generally looked slightly out of place). The username/email/password fields are too tall. Tapping a field shows a prev/next/done bar on top of the keyboard, just like Safari. While in the username field, the return key says "Go", tapping it causes an error message to appear *behind* the prev/next/done bar (the bar is translucent, but dark enough that the user might not even notice it) instead of changing to the next field.
- In all apps, non-native buttons took longer to respond to touches than native buttons (on the prev/next/done bar above the keyboard or the "close" button associated with the subsidiary Facebook/Yahoo/Google login webview).

And that's their "App Showcase", and I didn't even get very far since I don't care enough to create throwaway accounts because they can't be bothered supporting native login (which exists at least for Facebook).

Of course, if you don't mind quirky not-quite-native apps, that's your call.

Answer (score 2):

It's a "to each his own" world, but I lean toward LiveCode as my one stop shop for app making. As someone previously mentioned, there are many 'create a bad app quickly' solutions, but LiveCode strives to make the code easy to learn and use, while supporting modern features. Working with the lower level objective C isn't for everyone, but when you need a feature that's not there yet, you can either roll up your sleeves and create an external yourself, or reach out to the LC community. There are a few who specialize in providing awesome externals, like Monte. Now that LC is going open source, the power under the hood is only going to get better.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you wish to accomplish.

If you want cross-platform ease of use, [Titanium Mobile's Appcelerator](http://www.appcelerator.com/) is really good, especially if you already know JavaScript. However, personally, I have never found the performance and extensibility of these tools to be as robust as those of Objective-C's, but they do have the major advantage of being cross-platform.

If you want an iOS only content-driven application, [RareWire](http://content.rarewire.com) is an excellent solution. It doesn't require a Mac, and is all cloud based. My only real issue with RareWire is the lack of true processing power, and control statements.

Answer (score 1):

If you are targeting only IOS, is is better to develop application using objective C. But, if you are targeting multiple mobile platforms like android, iphone, blackberry you can use other frameworks like phonegap, kony etc.

Advantages of phone gap 
Knowledge of HTML, javascript and CSS would be sufficient.

Advantages of Kony
Knowledge of basic Luva coding would be sufficient.

If you are developing a web application, frameworks like phonegap would be better and if native application, using native frameworks would be better. This is my suggestion.

Comment: I would stay away from KONY. Buggy stack, non existing WYSIWYG, IDE "drag-n-drop" development paradigm generates code that crashes your app when mobile network goes down if you make a service call. Also KONY 5 is now JavaScript. No easy upgrade from 4->5

Comment: @itadapter, I am not sure about the other details you have provided. But regarding the no network condition, i think it can be handled in kony framework and application may not crash.

Comment: right, you need to hand-write all of that. The sold feature of "no code/just drag n drop" is a not usable one and even if there is a way to handle this with drag-n-drop you write code by dragging "IF" conditional actions which becomes absolutely unmaintainable for anything but most trivial things. There is no central app-level hook like "unhandledError" or "networkerror", the exceptions from native do not propagate properly into LUA code and cause LUA disruption 2-10 lines later in code with absolutely unrelated message

Answer (score 1):

This is just my opinion but I can spot an HTML/Javascript solution embedded in an iPhone app anywhere no matter what program created it. I prefer an app that was designed for the device not for the web and made to fit the device. my 2 cents.

The main advantage to me of an HTML/Javascript app is resizing to fit most any devices.

The main advantage to me of a Livecode app is the ability to exactly match the device it was built for.

Answer (score 0):

Two main reasons:

1. Performance issues due to lack of hardware acceleration.
2. Lack of flexibility to the kind of apps you can create. i.e only features that are supported by the 3rd parties. Whereas for native Objective C, the sky is the limit.

Answer (score 0):

The biggest advantage to any development platform is maximizing the revenue you generate over time for the same work.

Targeting iOS with Objective-C lets you target users of iPhone, iPod Touch, iPad. There's no mincing words here - you are learning an object-oriented derivative of C - one that is only applicable to Apple devices (lets not forget Mac OS X here too, though you have more options there).

Multi-platform (specifically with LiveCode) also opens up all major desktops (Windows, Linux, Mac OS X) and also Android devices. The IDE isn't a web app, and you can test out your ideas very, very quickly.